# How to clone function in cython? I getting SystemError: unknown opcode

Tags: python, metaprogramming, cython, opcode

In cpython this code would work:

```py
import inspect
from types import FunctionType


def f(a, b):  # line 5
    print(a, b)


f_clone = FunctionType(
    f.__code__,
    f.__globals__,
    closure=f.__closure__,
    name=f.__name__
)

f_clone.__annotations__ = {'a': int, 'b': int}
f_clone.__defaults__ = (1, 2)
print(inspect.signature(f_clone))  # (a: int = 1, b: int = 2)
print(inspect.signature(f))  # (a, b)
f_clone()  # 1 2
f(1, 2)  # 1 2
try:
    f()
except TypeError as e:
    print(e)  # f() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'a' and 'b'
```

However in cython when calling `f_clone`, I get:

```py
XXX lineno: 5, opcode: 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "test.py", line 5, in f  # line of f definitio
SystemError: unknown opcode
```

I need this to create a copy of class `__init__` method on each class creation and and modify its signature, but keep original `__init__` signature untouched.

**Edit:**
Changes made to signature of copied object must not affect runtime calls and needed only for inspection purposes.

Comment: I don't think this is likely to work. A Cython function type isn't the same as a `types.FunctionType`. `__code__` is largely a dummy object just to give it an attribute. Changing `__defaults__` doesn't look to affect the function called. I'd suggest you either abandon Cython for this bit of program, or look at finding a significantly different approach to this functionality (inheritance? create a new function that delegates to `__init__`?)

Comment: Actually, I don't want changes to affect function call in runtime. Just copy it as is and declare `__wrapped__` attribute pointing to the fake typed function. That part works, but copied function cannot be called anymore

Comment: You might want to see original context of a problem: https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/pull/1034

Comment: Something is strange here, because built-in functions (and def-functions produced by Cython are seen as such) don't have `__code__`, so you should not be able to create `f_clone`. But I'm not sure that the above holds for all versions Python/Cython versions - so maybe you should share how you build the extension and which versions you use.

Comment: @ead with the Cython option `binding=True` they are an object with most of the right attributes (although `__code__` is a dummy etc.). I think this option will become default fairly soon. I assume OP is using it (otherwise it'll break earlier, as you say). However the "old" Cython version without the attributes is probably something they'll have to take care of too

Comment: Thanks! So is there a way to clone cython function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am relatively convinced this is never going to work well. If I were you I'd modify your code to fail elegantly for unclonable functions (maybe by just using the original `__init__` and not replacing it, since this seems to be a purely cosmetic approach to generate prettier docstrings). After that you could submit an issue to the [Cython issue tracker](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues) - however the maintainers of Cython know that full-introspection compatibility with Python is very challenging, so may not be hugely interested.

One of the main reasons I think you should just handle the error rather than find a workaround is that Cython is not the only method to accelerate Python. For example Numba can generate classes containing JIT accelerated code, or people can write their own functions in C (either as a C-API function, or perhaps wrapped with Ctypes or CFFI). These are all situations where your rather fragile introspection approach is likely to break. Handling the error fixes it for all of these; while you're likely to need an individual workaround for each one, plus all the methods I haven't thought of, plus any that are developed in the future.

---

Some details about Cython functions: at the moment a Cython has a compilation option called `binding` that can generate functions in two different modes:

- With `binding=False` functions have the type `builtin_function_or_method`, which has minimum introspection capacities, and so no `__code__`, `__globals__`, `__closure__` (or most other) attributes.
- With `binding=True` functions have the type `cython_function_or_method`. This has improved introspection capacity, so does provide most of the expected annotations. However some of them are nonsense defaults - specifically `__code__`. The `__code__` attribute is expected to be Python bytecode, however Cython doesn't use Python bytecode (since it's compiled to C). Therefore it just provides a dummy attribute.

It looks like Cython defaults to `binding=True` when compiling a .py file and when compiling a regular (non-cdef) class, giving the behaviour you report. However, when compiling a .pyx file it currently defaults to `binding=False`. It's possible you may also want to handle the `binding=False` case in some circumstances too.

Having established that trying to create a regular Python function object with the `__code__` attribute of a `cython_function_or_method` isn't going to work, let's look at a few other options:

```
>>> print(f)
<cyfunction f at 0x7f08a1c63550>
>>> type(f)()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cannot create 'cython_function_or_method' instances
```

So you can't create your own `cython_function_or_method` and populate it from Python - the type does not have a user callable constructor.

`copy.copy` appears to work, but doesn't actually create a new instance:

```
>>> import copy
>>> copy.copy(f)
<cyfunction f at 0x7f08a1c63550>
```

Note, however, that this has exactly the same address - it isn't a copy:

```
>>> copy.copy(f) is f
True
```

At which point I'm out of ideas.

---

What I don't quite get is why you don't use [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps)?

```
@functools.wraps(f):
def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
```

This updates `wrapper` with most of the relevant introspection attributes from `f`, works for both types of Cython function (to an extent - the `binding=False` case doesn't provide much useful information), and should work for most other types of function too.

It's possible I'm missing something, but it seems a whole lot less fragile than your scheme of copying code objects.

Comment: Thanks! That actually what I'm end up with: wrapping original function with new one. I didn't considered this in python, since it would add redundant call to stack and could confuse user on debug. That's, however, not problem in cython, in which code you can't step in while debugging

Comment: I'd argue that the cost of a redundant call would be fairly low, especially for something like a constructor which is typically only used infrequently. I also don't think an extra item on the stack is too confusing - the exception is raised in the right place, and with a sensible name like `init_wrapper` it'd be pretty obvious what's going on. Anyway - that's my opinion, but you know your the code you're writing better than me